# How can I get UploadedFile (upload from out of box Sitecore Form) Blob / fileContent?

Tags: sitecore-client, xconnect, sitecore-api, sitecore-forms

How can I retrieve `Filecontent` from `[sitecore_forms_filestorage].[FileStorage]` based on `id` value? I tried the below code, but got a "`_fileStorageProvider` is `null`" error.

```
Guid fieldid = Guid.Parse("093d23aq-0986-12r5-131d-18pel8s2w6w14);           
StoredFile file = this._fileStorageProvider.GetFile(fieldid);
```

[image]

The full Controller code:

```
namespace test
{
    public class FileStorageController : Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreController
    {
        private readonly IFileStorageProvider _fileStorageProvider;
        private IFormDataProvider _dataProvider;
        public FileStorageController(IFileStorageProvider fileStorageProvider, IFormDataProvider formDataProvider)
        {
            this._fileStorageProvider = fileStorageProvider;
            this._dataProvider = formDataProvider;
        }
        public StoredFile GetFile()
        {
            Guid fieldid = Guid.Parse("093d23aq-0986-12r5-131d-18pel8s2w6w14");
            StoredFile file = this._fileStorageProvider.GetFile(fieldid);
            return file;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I call my custom Controller:

```
test.FileStorageController fs = new test.FileStorageController(_fileStorageProvider, _dataProvider);
StoredFile sf = fs.GetFile();
```

Comment: Can you check what sql queries are trigged when you submit the form or upload the file as well as when executing above Get API? Basically if possible share the sql traces. Check this link if it helps http://onelittlespark.bartverdonck.be/file-upload-for-sitecore-forms/

Comment: Could you please share more code where you define `fileStorageProvider` instance?

Comment: Kate, here is code. controller code :

Comment: namespace test{public class FileStorageController : Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreController
    { private readonly IFileStorageProvider _fileStorageProvider;
private IFormDataProvider _dataProvider;
public FileStorageController(IFileStorageProvider fileStorageProvider, IFormDataProvider formDataProvider)
{ this._fileStorageProvider = fileStorageProvider;
this._dataProvider = formDataProvider; }
 public  StoredFile GetFile()
 { Guid fieldid = Guid.Parse("093d23aq-0986-12r5-131d-18pel8s2w6w14");
 StoredFile file = this._fileStorageProvider.GetFile(fieldid);
return file;}}}

Comment: test.FileStorageController  fs = new test.FileStorageController(_fileStorageProvider, _dataProvider);
            StoredFile sf = fs.GetFile();

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code! Make sure that IFileStorageProvider is registered in IoC Container as you might have a dependency injection problem. Any other errors in the log?